# How to Create 3 Column Layout with CSS Only?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

I'm trying to correct an issue where the content section of my page has three columns but the DIVs are not floating appropriately.  Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>        

<div class="columns">
    <div id="borrower">
    </div>
    <div id="dealer">
    </div>
    <div id="investor">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
}
#content
{
background-image: url('../Images/background_03.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 1150px;
height: 399px;
}
#borrower
{
background-image: url('../Images/Borrower.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 371px;
height: 248px;
float: left;
}
#investor
{
background-image: url('../Images/Lender.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 371px;
height: 248px;
}
#dealer
{
background-image: url('../Images/dealer.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 371px;
height:248px;
float: right;
}
#footer
{
clear:both;
}
```

Using the above code, the Lender DIV is directly below the Borrower DIV instead of sitting in the middle between Borrower and Dealer.  How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than float:right you need to use float:left for each div elements. Unless you want one of your elements to be positioned away from the other two. If you want to add spacing between the div elements use margin-left.

http://jsfiddle.net/TxD6V/

Comment: I changed the float property for all 3 and now Borrower is far left, Dealer is next to Borrower, and Lender is below Borrower.

Comment: @SidC have the elements got enough room, or is their parent container too small to place all three elements on a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Please add "float:left;" in your investor id. The css is

```
#investor
{
background-image: url('../Images/Lender.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 371px;
height: 248px; float:left;
}
```

Thanks